# Bootstrap 4.4 carousel control buttons are in increct position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wrote a simple Carousel page based on the official documentation.
Reference link:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#with-controls

But the Carousel Control Button is not in the right position.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rssLl.jpg)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoHjG.jpg)

It seems the Carousel Control Button is in the vertical center of browser but not div element. How should I make it in vertical center of ?

My environment: Debian 10 / Bootstrap 4.4.1(installed by yarn)

here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white" style="z-index: 20;">
        <div class="container d-flex">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-50-5.jpg" style="height: 3rem;">
                ***
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">***<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-1280-1024-8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-1280-1024-7.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have just modified your snippet. Please check it. if any changes please let me know.

Comment: @RevtiShah thx, but still the same problem.

Comment: Wait I will check and let you know.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added arrows into **.carousel-inner** class. Hope now it will help you. if any changes please let me know.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white" style="z-index: 20;">
    <div class="container d-flex">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-50-5.jpg" style="height: 3rem;"> ***
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">***<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">***</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-1280-1024-8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-1280-1024-7.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, it works. actually, I have added arrows beyond .carousel class. I was careless.